# __init__ for unittest.TestCase

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'd like to add a couple of things to what the `unittest.TestCase` class does upon being initialized but I can't figure out how to do it.

Right now I'm doing this:

```
#filename test.py

class TestingClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def __init__(self):
        self.gen_stubs()

    def gen_stubs(self):
        # Create a couple of tempfiles/dirs etc etc.
        self.tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
        # more stuff here
```

I'd like all the stubs to be generated only once for this entire set of tests. I can't use `setUpClass()` because I'm working on Python 2.4 (I haven't been able to get that working on python 2.7 either).

What am I doing wrong here?

I get this error:

```
 `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 argument (2 given)`
```

...and other errors when I move all of the stub code into `__init__` when I run it with the command `python -m unittest -v test`.

Answer (score 235, accepted):

Try this:

```
class TestingClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestingClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.gen_stubs()
```

You are overriding the `TestCase`'s `__init__`, so you might want to let the base class handle the arguments for you.

Comment: This isn't working for me. The stuff inside gen_stub isn't being executed. Infact looks like gen_stub isn't being called at all... I can tell because the self.tempdir that's supposed to exist, cannot be accessed by the other methods of the class. I get a AttributeError: 'TestingClass' object has no attribute 'tempdir'

Comment: what makes you think so ? Can you put a break point or a print statement and see ?

Comment: @karthikr I'm using `os.listdir(self.stubdir)` and I get the aforementioned error.

I've also added a print "something" right after the gen_stubs call. That doesn't seem to be run either.

Comment: should you not be calling this in `setUp` rather than overriding `__init__` ?

Comment: @karthikr I want to generate the stubs once for all the tests rather than recreate them for every test everytime. Some of the stubs will not even be used by some of the tests. I would use setUpClass, but I don't think python 2.4 supports it.

Comment: Sorry, I have not worked on 2.4. If this helps, just today I was using this snippet: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1318/ It is not exactly what you are looking for, but should give you the idea.

Comment: Also, looking at the documentation, it doesnt look like `setUP` is not supported: http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#setupclass-and-teardownclass They mention which version supports a feature specifically if it is not available since 2.1

Comment: You can also be a little more explicit in this case (which helps with readability in my opinion) and use: `unittest.TestCase.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)` instead of `super(TestingClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 70):

Just wanted to add some clarifications about overriding the init function of

```
unittest.TestCase
```

The function will be called before each method in your test class. Please note that if you want to add some expensive computations that should be performed **once** before running all test methods please use the [SetUpClass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass) classmethod

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.attribute1 = some_expensive_computation()
```

This function will be called **once** before all test methods of the class. See `setUp` for a method that is called before each test method.

Comment: "The function will be called before each method in your test class." thought the TestCase was Initialized only once

Answer (score -2):

Install unittest2 and use that package's unittest.

```
import unittest2
```

and then use the setupModule / tearDownModule or setupClass / tearDown class 
for special initialization logic

More info: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/unittest2.shtml

Also most likely your are creating an integration test more than an unittest. 
Choose a good name for the Tests to differentiate them or put in a different container module.

Comment: It is not relevant to the question, requires additional software and the link is invalid.