# Python: Where to put a one time initialization in a test case of unittest framework?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, python-unittest

My test is simple. I want to send two requests to two different servers then compare whether the results match.

I want to test the following things.

1. send each request and see whether the return code is valid.
2. compare different portion of the outputs in each test method

I do not want to send the requests in setUp method because it will be send over and over for each new test. I would rather want to send the requests at the initialization. (maybe in the **init** method). But I found a lot of people were against that idea because they believe I should not override the init method for some reason. (I do not know exactly why) If that's the case, where should I send the requests?
I am kind of against doing them in the class body (as shared variables).

Comment: I'd personally send the requests in a test case.  You can still split up the checks on the result into several methods; just choose names that don't start with `test`, so they won't be called as test cases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between setUpClass and setUp in Python unittest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667610/difference-between-setupclass-and-setup-in-python-unittest)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\_\_init\_\_ for unittest.TestCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353213/init-for-unittest-testcase)

Answer (score 5):

A class method called before tests in an individual class run. setUpClass is called with the class as the only argument and must be decorated as a classmethod():

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    ...
```

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass