# TypeError when using unittest.main() in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm writing a test case with Python. This used to work for me but now I'm getting an error. Here is my code:

```
import unittest

class ParsePEDataTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def test_(self):
        print 'test test'





if __name__=='__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The error this is giving me is:

```
  File "c:\anaconda2\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 56, in loadTestsFromTestCase
    loaded_suite = self.suiteClass(map(testCaseClass, testCaseNames))

TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I've ran some of my old tests and I get the same error. Does anybody know what is going on?

Comment: You shouldn't implement `__init__` in your test class. Are you looking for `setUp` or `setUpClass`?

Comment: If you need to use the `__init__` method of a test case, do it correctly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353213/init-for-unittest-testcase.

Comment: Aaah of course. Thanks