# Flask app created twice during python unittest

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest

I have an app.py file which creates an flask app

```
def create_app():
       app = Flask(__name__)
       return app
```

I am trying to write an unittest for my module and below is the file

```
from app import create_app
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app()
        self.client = self.app.test_client()
        ctx = self.app.app_context()
        ctx.push()

    def test_healthcheck(self):
        res = self.client.get("/")
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)

    def test_tenant_creation(self):
        res = self.client.post("/tenants")
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
```

When i run individual test methods it is working fine. But when i run the entire test case , the create app is called again which causes issues since my create app has dependencies which needs to be called only once.

Is it possible to create app only once ?

Comment: Say more about the problematic dependencies. Why only once?

Answer (score 1):

[setUp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp) gets called before *each* test method. Therefore, if you run the whole test case, it will be called twice (one for each test method).

To run something only once for the `TestCase`, you could try overriding the `__init__` method (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353213/init-for-unittest-testcase)), or [setUpClass or setUpModule](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#setupclass-and-teardownclass). YMMV depending on which python version and test runners you are using.

Answer (score -1):

IMO, the problem may related with context. You should create a `tearDown()` method to destroy the application context you created in `setUp()`:

```
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app()
        self.client = self.app.test_client()
        self.ctx = self.app.app_context()
        self.ctx.push()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.ctx.pop()
```